# python & pandas -- generate multiple columns from 2 columns of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I would like to go from this ..

```
type  cost
dog   5
dog   2
cat   4
rat   6
```

to this ..

```
dog cat rat
 5   0   0
 2   0   0
 0   4   0
 0   0   6
```

this almost works...

```
pd.concat([ tbl1['type'].astype(str) == x for x in ['dog','cat','rat']], 1, keys=['dog','cat','rat'])
```

but ... I get a table of True/False values

I am trying t avoid a for-loop for generating N number of columns, because in reality I might need to have 100+ columns for different values in 'type' column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for filtering and categories are generated by `unique`:

```
c = df['type'].unique()
df = pd.concat([df.loc[df['type'] == x, 'cost'] for x in c], 1, keys=c).fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
   dog  cat  rat
0    5    0    0
1    2    0    0
2    0    4    0
3    0    0    6
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html)

```
df.pivot_table(values='cost', index=df.index, columns='type', aggfunc='first').fillna(0)

type  cat  dog  rat
0       0    5    0
1       0    2    0
2       4    0    0
3       0    0    6
```

Answer (score 3):

`get_dummies` + `dot` -

```
v = pd.get_dummies(df.type)
v[:] = v.values * df.cost.values[:, None]

v
   cat  dog  rat
0    0    5    0
1    0    2    0
2    4    0    0
3    0    0    6
```

Comment: this is a really slick solution. I gave the correct answer to the first answer, but still want to give big credit here

Comment: @sam So why don’t you [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) it?

Comment: @sam First != best. You can upvote all solutions you found useful. You can also accept any answer you like, not just the first one.

Comment: Personally, I dislike when users decide to arbitrarily award answers based on how fast they were posted. Please evaluate each answer on its own merits, test each one on your data, see which one is the best/fastest/most efficient, and accept that.

Comment: just reading this now. sorry for delayed response.In the answer I choose, I like the "fillna" option just because instead of 0s I could set some other default value. I did not pick the first answer just because it was the first. my first comment should have been clearer

Comment: @sam okay, sure. Although if that was a criteria, you could've mentioned it in the question, and hence the answers could've changed accordingly. ;)